# How is this code working and what is it doing? (GDI, C#)

Tags: c#, gdi

I'm currently following a tutorial on youtube to make a 2D Game Engine. I've never done anything with GDI before but have good knowledge with OpenGL in both C# and C++.

However, I don't quite understand whats going on here and would love an explanation.

Here's the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Drawing;

namespace GameEngine
{
    public class GraphicsEngine
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// A reference to the game window
        /// </summary>
        private Window window;

        /// <summary>
        /// Responsible for rendering graphics to the screen
        /// </summary>
        private Graphics screenBuffer;

        /// <summary>
        /// Responsible for sending the back buffer bitmap to the screen buffer.
        /// </summary>
        private Graphics backBuffer;

        /// <summary>
        /// Responsible for drawing graphics into memory
        /// </summary>
        private Bitmap backBufferBitmap;

        public GraphicsEngine(Window window)
        {
            this.window = window;
        }

        public void Initialize()
        {
            this.screenBuffer = window.CreateGraphics();
            this.backBufferBitmap = new Bitmap(window.Width, window.Height);
        }

        public void Update()
        {
            try
            {
                // copy back buffer to screen buffer
                screenBuffer = Graphics.FromImage(backBufferBitmap);

                // draw the back buffer to the screen
                backBuffer = window.CreateGraphics();
                backBuffer.DrawImage(backBufferBitmap, 0, 0, window.Width, window.Height);

                // clear the buffer
                Clear(Color.Wheat);
            }
            catch (System.ObjectDisposedException)
            {
                Environment.Exit(0);
            }
        }

        private void Clear(Color color)
        {
            screenBuffer.Clear(color);
        }
    }
}
```

So, as far as I can tell. The screenBuffer object is set to the windows graphics object upon initialisation. Then the backBufferBitmap is set the windows width and height and is essentially stored into memory to later be drawn to. If I'm wrong, let me know.

However, the update method... It just makes no sense to me...

Comment: Are you able to be more specific about what part of the update method makes no sense to you? I think the comments in the code are pretty self explanatory to me and I don't know much about GDI or OpenGL.

Comment: The code posted is buggy (it should use `screenBuffer.DrawImage`, not `backBuffer.DrawImage`) and slow (it should only call `Graphics.FromImage` once, not on every `Update` invokation). Perhaps that's what's causing your confusion?

Comment: What I don't understand is what the backBufferBitmap is doing and why it is needed. And also why the backbuffer is drawing an image and not the screenBuffer.

Comment: The variable names in the code are *very* silly, especially "backBuffer" got a wildly inappropriate name.  It just paints a bitmap on the window, that is all.  Don't use it, it is buggy.

Comment: @HansPassant Naming something inappropriately doesn't make it 'buggy'. The bottom line is I've stated I don't even understand half of it, so I wouldn't even know what to change it too haha. Feel free to enlighten me a little as to what I should be naming it.